# Bisectors in symmetric spaces

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, hyperbolic-geometry

In William Goldman's book Complex Hyperbolic Geometry, bisector hypersurfaces play an important role. Given two points $x,y$, the bisector is the set of points equidistant from $x$ and from $y$. Do they also play an important role in the study of higher rank symmetric spaces, and do they admit concrete descriptions, say in the Siegel upper half-plane? References are especially welcome.

Comment: One of the interest of bisectors is to prove that some non-arithmetic groups of isometries are nonetheless discrete by constructing fundamental domains for their action. Higher rank spaces are much more rigid, and all lattices are arithmetic. This does not mean that bissectors are useless, but their purpose seems less obvious, and it will probably be more difficult to find relevant literature.

Comment: One might still be interested in constructing a nice fundamental domain for a discrete group, even if one already knows a priori whether the group is arithmetic.

Comment: In higher rank the most useful bisectors appear in the case of $SL(n)$ where instead of the Riemannian metric one uses a non -symmetric metric defined by Selberg in his 1960 paper. The key is that Selberg's bisectors are linear, unlike the Riemannian ones. 

Comment: Thanks. This is Selberg's paper `On discontinuous groups...'? I'll see if I can get a hold of that. I'm not very worried if the bisectors are linear or not. I just want to build a fundamental domain for a group generated by some translations in the Siegel upper half-plane, where by translation I mean `$Z \mapsto Z + B$`, $B$ a symmetric matrix.  

Comment: OK. I looked at Selberg's paper. I've never seen something like that before. I think that I'm still interested in the Riemannian metric, but this Selberg thing could be useful too. Does it appear commonly? Are there other more extended references? He talks about one case, SL(n), and doesn't say very much.

Comment: Selberg's construction was not used much, but it has advantages over the Riemannian one since equations for bisectors in his case are linear, you can also easily identify intersections of bisectors. You can also apply it for other symmetric spaces by embedding them isometric ally to the symmetric space for SL(n). If you are interested in algorithmic aspects of fundamental domains, Selberg's construction would work better than Riemannian one. I did not check this, but Selberg's construction might be related to classical reduction theory for lattices. 

Comment: Thanks. I'll think about this. I have a family of examples where I'm pretty sure the Riemannian bisectors will provide walls for a fundamental domain, but I don't know how to check this because I don't know how to explicitly describe them. Selberg's bisectors might work as well and look more computable. I'll think about it. But they look less likely to behave well with respect to maps between symmetric spaces, no?

Comment: Selberg's bisectors are only defined for some types of symmetric spaces, most importantly, for the type A. Thus, if you have a symmetric space for type, say, C, you embed it in the one of type A and use bisectors coming from the ambient space. Computations with Riemannian bisectors are notoriously difficult even with modern computers. 

Answer (score 3):

Although I cannot address your specific question, of whether bisectors "play an important role in the study of higher rank symmetric spaces," 
I can say that
bisectors are the essence of [Voronoi diagrams](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voronoi_diagram).
So the 
2009 paper by
Frank Nielsen and Richard Nock, entitled
"Hyperbolic Voronoi diagrams made easy"
([arXiv link)](http://arxiv.org/abs/0903.3287), could well be relevant:

> We present a simple framework to compute hyperbolic Voronoi diagrams of finite point sets as affine diagrams. We prove that *bisectors* in Klein's non-conformal disk model are hyperplanes that can be interpreted as power bisectors of Euclidean balls. [...]

[image: Hyperbolic VorDiag]

Comment: That's a nice reference, but hyperbolic space is Rank 1, which means, in particular, that there are totally geodesic hyperplanes, which are the bisectors. In higher rank, there are no totally geodesic hyperplanes, so the whole theory (to the extent it exists at all) is \emph{completely} different.

Comment: Also cool pictures. But yes, I'm particularly interested in higher rank, especially the Siegel upper half-plane.